# qs-01-php-embed-signing-ceremony.php user does not belong to account problem

Tags: php, docusignapi

I am having an issue with the DocuSign API where I am getting an `USER_DOES_NOT_BELONG_TO_SPECIFIED_ACCOUNT` error when attempting to authenticate.

First, I set a url in the website. The url carries my api key and redirection address. The user clicks to access it. Go to the `account-d.docusign.com` login page and log in to authorize me. I obtained the access token through the returned authorization code, and then called the `embedded_signing_ceremony` method to return the envelope view. I set `$ accountId` to my own API Account ID Something went wrong.

```
Caught exception: Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code [400] with response Body: O: 8: "stdClass": 2: {s: 9: "errorCode"; s: 41: "USER_DOES_NOT_BELONG_TO_SPECIFIED_ACCOUNT"; s: 7: "message"; s: 60: "The specified User is not a member of the specified Account.";} DocuSign API error information: string (166) "O: 8:" stdClass ": 2: {s: 9 : "errorCode"; s: 41: "USER_DOES_NOT_BELONG_TO_SPECIFIED_ACCOUNT"; s: 7: "message"; s: 60: "The specified User is not a member of the specified Account.";} "
```

```php
function embedded_signing_ceremony($user_name,$user_sub,$user_email,$user_token){
    #
    # The document $fileNamePath will be signed by <signer_name> via an
    # embedded signing ceremony.

    # Settings
    # Fill in these constants
    #
    # Obtain an OAuth access token from https://developers.docusign.com/oauth-token-generator
    $accessToken=$user_token;
   # Obtain your accountId from demo.docusign.com -- the account id is shown in the drop down on the
    # upper right corner of the screen by your picture or the default picture. 
    $accountId ="0fe939e9-73bb-48e3-8887-e32d581ba578";  
  # Recipient Information:
    $signerName = $user_name;
    $signerEmail =$user_email;
    # The document you wish to send. Path is relative to the root directory of this repo.
    $fileNamePath = 'qs-php-master/demo_documents/World_Wide_Corp_lorem.pdf';
    # The url of this web application's folder. If you leave it blank, the script will attempt to figure it out.
    $baseUrl = '';
    $clientUserId =$user_sub; #  Used to indicate that the signer will use an embedded
                        # Signing Ceremony. Represents the signer's userId within
                        # your application.
    $authenticationMethod = 'None'; # How is this application authenticating
                                    # the signer? See the `authenticationMethod' definition
                                    # https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient

    # The API base_path
    $basePath = 'https://demo.docusign.net/restapi';

    # Constants
    $appPath = getcwd();
```

When the user account_id is set to `$accountId`, I can return the envelope view url, but this is not the result I want, it should be that I created the envelope and displayed it to the user for signature

I want to know how to set it up to achieve the effect I want

Comment: Hi @alex, it's much more convenient for peopole to help you if all the code is viewable as text instead of a separate image - could you remove the image and replace it with the code itself?

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time using Stack Overflow, I have modified it and don't know if it is the norm

Comment: That's okay @alex, that seems better to me - I'm just trying to help you improve the quality of the question so that you can get the help you need from people that know the topic area!

Answer (score 0):

There are two GUIDs used when using JWT:

1. AccountID - this is the overall account being used.
2. UserID - this is the user that will be impersonated.

Now when you try to call an API, it will be using the user from #2 above. The account is on the URL and the env in your case is Demo/Sandbox.

Ensure that all three point to the same place- URL goes to correct environment, userId and accountID match the specific account you're using and the correct user from the correct environment.